# How can I highlight a row based on a cell's color using VBA in Excel with a dropdown value?

Tags: excel, vba

Highlight Row Based On Cell Colour

I was using a conditional format that highlights a NPS value in a column based on a chosen dropdown value. From there I wanted to highlight the data that belonged to that NPS value. I was initially going to use this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range("B12:B34")
For Each c In MyRange

If UCase(c.Value) = "$B$9" Then //fix this??
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow //modify to range rather than entire
Else
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If


Next

End Sub
```

Also tried this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range("B12:B34")
For Each c In MyRange

If UCase(c.Value) = Cells(2, 9) Then //fix this??
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow //modify to range rather than entire
Else
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If


Next

End Sub
```

This code works fine if i set "If UCase(c.Value) = " to a numeric value like 0.125, 0.25, etc.

Also, i was not sure how to set a boundary/range to "c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow" i.e("B:F") rather than the whole row.

The table gives a gist of what I want. When i select a value like 1.00 it should highlight everything to the right of it. (Specific OD, ID, Thickness, and LB/FT relative to 1.00)

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Range("B12:B34")
For Each c In MyRange

If UCase(c.Value) = 1 Then
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
Else
    c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

[Data Table] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjHbV.png)

[Corrected Data Table] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmKeS.png)

[Dropdown] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlx4X.png)

[Conditional Format] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Qs9.png)

$B9: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qudr0.png

$B$9: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRUrA.png

Changed formula to include range: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG6Vp.png

Screen Cap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFEbf.png

Comment: Is there a reason you don't extend the conditional formatting to the row(s)?

Comment: I would have to add a second conditional format that would be based on colour of the cell under NPS. Didnt think it was possible b/c all the formats are based on numeric/text formats and not colour. Unless there is a certain formula for colour selection with respect to the row and cell.?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your screencap where any given cell is. (i.e. where is cell B9?) can you please include the column headers, row numbers ?

Comment: Ya sure my bad, it should be there now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a condition like

```
=$B12=$B$9
```

(Pay attention to the absolute/relative coordinates for the cells)

And apply it to the entire table

[image]

Sample result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton I did not even think to do it this way!

Comment: It does not work without me inputting 23 individual rows which was not the solution I was looking for. I am not sure if its to do with the dropdown. But this was not the solution I was looking for

Comment: Look at the relative/absolute references in your equation. You may need something like: `$B9` instead of `$B$9` (as in your screencap). If that's not it, maybe explain the condition you are trying to apply

Comment: Tried both references and neither work. I edited the post above to include pictures

Comment: Essentially I am trying to avoid 23 if statements and have it so that depending on dropdown conditions the cells highlighted will change with respect to the dropdown value

Comment: See the edits to my answer

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Highlight Rows of Matches

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const DROP_DOWN_CELL As String = "B9"
    Const TABLE_FIRST_CELL As String = "B11"
    Const TABLE_COLUMN_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = vbYellow
    
    Dim ddCell As Range: Set ddCell = Me.Range(DROP_DOWN_CELL)
    
    If Intersect(ddCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With Me.Range(TABLE_FIRST_CELL).CurrentRegion
        drCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If drCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    End With

    Dim ddValue: ddValue = ddCell.Value

    Dim urg As Range
    
    If IsNumeric(ddValue) Then
        
        Dim rrg As Range, rValue
    
        For Each rrg In drg.Rows
            rValue = rrg.Cells(TABLE_COLUMN_INDEX)
            If IsNumeric(rValue) Then
                If rValue = ddValue Then
                    If urg Is Nothing Then
                        Set urg = rrg
                    Else
                        Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next rrg
        
     End If
     
     drg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     
     If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     
     urg.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR

End Sub
```